# what could make COUNT and GROUP BY block my query when it took 0,2s to be done before?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is blocked on the "Sending data" status:

```
SELECT      
count(*)   
FROM `text_reference` tr      
LEFT JOIN `text_file` tf ON  tf.`id_text_reference`=tr.`id`
```

It is a very simple query and when I do not use the COUNT, it take less than one second for aggregating 110 000 lines.
But with the COUNT(), it takes more than 30s.

I have the same issue with the GROUP BY function:

```
SELECT      
*
FROM `text_reference` tr      
LEFT JOIN `text_file` tf ON  tf.`id_text_reference`=tr.`id` 
GROUP BY tr.`reference`
```

The columns 'id' and 'reference' are primary keys, so indexed.

I do not undersand how such a change is possible.
Furthermore, everything was absolutely fine before I added a new column to the 'text_reference' table.
I restarted MySQL and Apache and flushed the cache but nothing worked.
So could you please help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of `text_reference` and `text_file` as well.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of A) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'text_reference'; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'text_file'; for more complete analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you interest but I finally found the solution.
It was because the index on one of the table was badly done.
And sorry for the late answer!